# Constant vs. instance variable vs. instance method

Tags: ruby, variables, methods, constants

I have a base class `A` containing a public method which works with an array provided by descendants of A. The array is:

- used only by the methods defined in the base class `A`
- constant, but there are special cases in which it varies.

How should I approach the object design of the problem thus defined? I am still not sure myself where to store that array, whether in a constant, an instance variable or an instance method. Please show me how to do this.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: According to what does the result vary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last time I was evil to a female newbie. This time over, I'll try to be nice.

Way one, using a constant:

```
A = Class.new

class B < A
  FOO = [ :hello, :world ] # this is your array
end

# Access different constants defined in different descendants is tricky, like this:

class A
  def foo_user
    puts self.class.const_get :FOO
  end
end

B.new.foo_user #=> [ :hello, :world ]

# Note theat you can't do this:

class A
  def foo_user
    puts FOO # this would look for FOO in A mother class only
  end
end

 B.new.foo_user #=> error
```

Way two, using an instance variable belonging to the subclasses of A:

```
A = Class.new

class B < A
  @foo = [ "hello", "world" ]
end

# This way is more usable. I would go about it like this:

class A
  class << self
    attr_reader :foo     # defining a reader class method
  end

  def foo
    self.class.foo       # delegating foo calls on the instances to the class
  end

  def foo_user
    puts foo
  end
end

B.new.foo_user #=> [ :hello, :world ]
```

Way three, using an instance method defined on the descendants:

```
A = Class.new

class B < A
  def foo
    [ "hello", "world" ]
  end
end

# This way is also usable.

class A
  def foo_user
    puts foo
  end
end
```

The choice between the way 2 (instance variable belonging to a descendant class) and 3 (method defined on a descendant class) depends on how flexible the value (the array) needs to be. Way 2 is most flexible, but way 3 takes less code.

Comment: Thanks for being nice, I choose the way 3.

Comment: downvoted because you shouldn't be patted on the back for merely being decent.